# Div's float lower or higher based on the text within them

Tags: html, css

On [my website](https://pudgypoppins.github.io/#projects), if you scroll down to projects, you'll see some divs with a background-image and another slightly opacic div over them. My problem is, the more that I write in side of them, the higher on the page they are. I've tried using overflow scroll and margin-top. However, I can't find a way to lower them all into a grid-like fashion. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: It might not be obvious, but SO is aimed at helping programmers learn to program. Your question should be in the form of: ***why isn't my code working? I think it should!*** rather than in the form of ***I need this coded, please! thank you for your help in advance***

Comment: And by the way, Andrei is right.

Comment: @Pudgy, You're getting downvoted for a few reasons but the biggest may be asking us to go to your website (unknown link!) to look at your problem in situ. Please copy a relevant snippet here and give some specific examples of what you changed that you expected would help but did not. Good luck!

Comment: I was unaware of how to ask good questions on Stack Overflow. Your comments have been helpful. In my future questions I will make sure to incorporate your advice, and make sure my questions include enough information to allow further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#projectlust {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: You should not answer questions that show no research effort whatsoever. They will be downvoted and hence they will get less visits. Hence, your awesomely useful answer will help fewer people. So your skills are much better used on good questions.

Comment: I agree with you. Next time I will try don't answer question which are very low quality and don't show any personal effort. Because I want to retain SO uncluttered and useful.